# Quickest way to modify/reload existing Linux driver

Tags: linux, driver

I am trying to understand an existing Linux Wi-Fi driver for a USB Wi-Fi adapter.  While I can read the C code, I would also like to be able to insert debug/print statements at certain critical spots in the driver to see how it behaves when executed.  On a Linux system, after modifying the driver code, how does one go about loading it into the kernel in such a way that it replaces the old driver?  Is there a way to "hotplug substitute" it straight over the old driver, or is it more complicated than that?

I intend on doing this inside of an expendible virtual machine, so I am not concerned about messing up the original driver, for what it counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the driver is compiled as a module, all you need to do is to add your debug print outs, compile the module, `rmmod` the original module, `insmod` your new module and initiate the WLAN connection as usual.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test and edit on the fly :

- `lsmod` to find the module name
- `rmmod` it
- edit source
- Make sur you got a Makefile : `obj-m := module_name.o`
- recompile (on Ubuntu) : `make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-'uname -r' M='pwd' modules`
- `insmod module_name.ko`

If it's a device module, you might want to rm  any devices in /dev, then do a `mknod` to remake them (see mknod man) and finally `chmod` to correct rights.